# INNER JOIN in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little problem with INNER JOIN in mysql query. I have two tables the first is 'kontrola' and 2nd is 'naruszenia' In 'kontrola' table I have rows:

- id
- podmiot
- miasto
- wszczeto
- zakonczono
- naruszenie_id (Foreign KEY on 'naruszenia' table)
  In my naruszenia table I have:
- id
- naruszenia

Now I want to display using INNER JOIN the naruszenie from 'naruszenia' table.
I've create somethin linke this:

```
$listakontroli = $connecting->query("SELECT * FROM kontrola INNER JOIN naruszenia ON
 kontrola.naruszenie_id=naruszenia.id");
```

But the result is that when I want to display records in table I have changed the ID of first table(kontrola) and the naruszenia_id still showing id from naruszenia table. How to change it to display properly the word not id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could  use explicit column name  and refer to both the table (in this case using k an n) eg:

```
$listakontroli = $connecting->query("SELECT k.id
           , k.podmiot
           , k.miasto
           , k.wszczeto7
           , k.zakonczono
           , n.naruszenia 
      FROM kontrola k
      INNER JOIN naruszenia  n ON  k.naruszenie_id=n.id");
```

Comment: scaisEdge maybe You can write me how to fix the query to INSERT now in to the DB the new record belong to kontrola table?

Comment: @killerbees   .you should . post a new question properly described  and comment me the related link so i can take a look

Comment: scaisEdge I've create a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49339313/how-to-insert-new-record-in-mysql-db-using-two-tables

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or separate the `ID` from the two tables. e.g.

```
$listakontroli = $connecting->query("SELECT kontrola.id as kid, naruszenia.id as nid, podmiot, miasto, etc* FROM kontrola INNER JOIN naruszenia ON  kontrola.naruszenie_id=naruszenia.id");
```

This way you can properly distinguish the displayed IDs