# How to Insert new record in mysql db using two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little problem. I've create a two tables 'kontrola' and 'naruszenie'. In kontrola table I have a foreign key relation to 'naruszenie' table. When I want to display all records belong to 'kontrola' table I use this:

```
$listakontroli = $connecting->query("SELECT k.id, k.podmiot, k.miasto, k.wszczeto, k.zakonczono, n.naruszenie FROM kontrola k INNER JOIN naruszenia n ON k.naruszenie_id=n.id");
```

And everything working properly.
How to create a query INSERT TO to add the new record using this 2 tables?
EDIT:

Now I have query like this but doesn't work

```
$dodajKontrole = "INSERT INTO kontrola (podmiot, miasto, wszczeto, zakonczono, naruszenie_id) VALUES ('$nowyPodmiot', '$noweMiasto', '$datawszczecia', '$datazakonczenia', '$nowenaruszenie')";
```

Comment: explain better  .where . you want insert the result of the select  ? in which table??

Comment: I want to add the new record in  'kontrola' table. Now I've create the query like in edit.

Comment: What do you mean with `doesn't work`?

Comment: When i cick add new record button the script not added me new record. Maybe the reason is with the primary Key, because now I have relations between tables.

Comment: nowenaruszenie in the select is a string in your table is an id (integer i guess)  .. are you sure you want insert the nowenaruszenie (name)

Comment: scaisEdge I want to add nowenaruszenie in to the 'naruszenia' table. I have to create seperate query for it?

Comment: yes is not possibile insert into two table with a single insert query  ..

Comment: So how to write in the two tables the datas sends by POST from 1 form?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a mysql TRIGGER if you want to do it in mySQL level

```
  CREATE TRIGGER insert_into_naruszenia AFTER INSERT ON `kontrola`
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
     INSERT INTO naruszenia (naruszenie) VALUES (NEW.id)
  END;

  INSERT INTO kontrola (....) VALUES (....);
```

I didn't test it but is should do the job.

If you want to use it inside php code you always have the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` that you can use.

```
  INSERT INTO kontrola (....) VALUES (....);
  INSERT INTO naruszenie (id) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID());
```